# Saving images from plotly

Tags: python, plotly

How can I save images generated with plotly in different formats? Only "Download as PNG" is possible from the generated HTML figure. I would need to interact with the figure (change rotation, choose which data to plot) and save an .eps figure for each online modified plot. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plotly supports exporting to EPS (the docs mention that you need the `poppler` library) and the `Figure` object has a `write_image` method that saves a figure to a file.

You can specify the format through the filename and the resolution with the `width` and `height` keyword arguments, representing logical pixels.

You can read more on static image exporting in Plotly [here](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/). This is a code example:

```
fig.write_image("name.eps", width=1920, height=1080)
```

In order to select what is plotted you will have to set the figure's [camera controls](https://plotly.com/python/3d-camera-controls/).